# stretching the background image in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, background-image

I have a background image. I am stretching it so that it fits the entire page.But it is working in browsers other than IE.But if I use background-size, it is working in IE9. But I want it to work in IE8. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

In other browsers and in IE9:
[image]

In IE8:
[image]

You can find the difference at the bottom of the page.
Here is my code:

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body.BodyBackground {

    margin: 0px;
    background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png);
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top center; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background-size:contain;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: transparent;


}

div.content{    
    height:100%;
    width:97%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
    height:470px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;

}
```

Comment: `background: url(../images/common/header/Background_color.png) #yourColorFromBottomOfImage;`

Comment: I didnt get you. Could you please be a bit more clear?

Comment: Just open your background image in photoshop(or any other software) and grab bottom color of your image. Then replace my `#yourColorFromBottomOfImage` with color you've grabbed.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to solve this issue through code?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle then. Btw, which version of IE?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `background-size` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: Then what am I supposed to do

Comment: I've already told you in my first comment. Isn't it an option to you?

Comment: but I tried giving some color like red,black in the place of #yourColorFromBottomOfImage...But it doesnt work

Comment: Remove `background-color: transparent;` and try again

Comment: yes. It is working. Now if I want to include some image, I am supposed to use another url() after first url(). right?

Comment: Morpheus: IF I use two url(), then second url replaces the first url

Comment: That's how it should be. You can't have to background images(I think CSS3 supports multiple images), but as you want in IE8 it will not work. Create another element and add second background image to it.

Comment: here I have "body.BodyBackground ". Should I need to create another element,say, "body.BodyBackground2"?. In jsp file, I have used <body class="body.BodyBackground ">. If I have another element and if I specify it in class attribute, will it not override the first  one?

Comment: Yes, it will. Use multiple classes in this case, something like `<body class="BodyBackground BodyBackground2">`

Comment: Second class is overriding the first class. So second image is only getting displayed

Comment: this can be achieved, see my answer

Answer (score 4):

IE8 does not support `background-size` property.

You have the following options:

- Use a background graphic that doesn't need stretching.
- Provide IE8 with a different background image (or no background image at all)
  *[edit]* See [my blog post on the subject](http://spudley.com/blog/) for more info on how to achieve this in pure CSS with no browser hacks.
- Ignore the problem and let IE8 users see a slightly broken site.
- Use a polyfill script like CSS3Pie to add the `background-size` feature to IE8.

If you really want to use `background-size`, and you really need to support IE8, then the last of those options is probably the best one for you.

Comment: note: you'll need css3pie v2 for the background-size feature.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 is going to implement a background-size attribute. But it isn't supported in IE<9.

If you want to scale a background gradient, you may use the img element because it is scaling. Instead of using a background to display the PNG, you now use an img element, and set the width and the height to 100%.

I think that this is what you want:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#page img {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <img src="../images/common/header/Background_color.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I do like this, I am getting two portions. One is displaying just the background and another is just displaying the content.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst like other answers state `background-size` is not supported is true.
There are other ways this can be achieved.

---

You can use the following to achieve stretched backgrounds in old IE.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Other sizing options for `sizingMethod`:

- **crop** Clips the image to fit the dimensions of the object.
- **image** Default. Enlarges or reduces the border of the object to fit the dimensions of the image.
- **scale** Stretches or shrinks the image to fill the borders of the object.

---

It is important you do not use this on the `html` or `body` tag.
Instead, create a `fixed` position div with 100% width and height.