# Resizing an image relative to viewport width

Tags: css, html

Hi all in my website there is a full width banner there. I made this banner in photoshop (with width:1350px and height:375px) I use the following css and html for accessing this.

```
#slider {
 margin-top:10px;
 height:375px;
 background:url(../Home/banner1.jpg) no-repeat center left;
}
```

I want to resize this banner proportionately when browser size is changed (like in the banners on the site http://www.endpolio.org/). If I put another size in

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.....
}
```

it will only resize at that particular width. I want to resize my image in every pixel (both width and height). How is it possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-size:contain` in order to preserve proportion.

Here is a shorthand, `background:url('') 0px 0px / contain no-repeat;`

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4wAc/)

**Updated CSS:**

```
#slider {
    width:100%;
    height:375px;
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1350x375') 0px 0px / contain no-repeat;
}
```

Just modify the height of the `#slider`.

See MDN for information on `background-size` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: thank you its working. but still i have a problem the height always remain 375 px( blank space) when size reduces bottom content is not placed in upward

Comment: @Parvathiiiii Hmm.. not really sure what you mean by that - can you please provide me an example? :)

Comment: @JoshC: i mean below #slider there is another div  #content, when the background in #slider is resized, the background image will be resized, but still the div's height is still 375 px. so there is big gap(blank space) between these two div

Comment: @Parvathiiiii I'm still trying to figure that out.. You **could** just use an `img` tag, and set `img { width:100%; height auto;}` that's all I can think of so far.. I will figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-size:contain
```

The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.
[background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

For ie - CSS3Pie ,more [stretching the background image in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478693/stretching-the-background-image-in-ie)